# how to do recommendation on imbalanced dataset of Recommender Systems

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

Pls. tell me how to do recommendation on imbalanced dataset of Recommender Systems.
As per my knowledge one need to create training and testing files for each user, having their ratings as the class label. For Ex:
Suppose user have given `Item1`, `Item4` and `Item3` `rating 5`, 5 and 1 respectively and we want to predict his rating for `Item6`
For a `user1` the training data will be:

```
User1_F1,User1_F2,......................Item1_F1,Item1_F2....,5
User1_F1,User1_F2,......................Item4_F1,Item4_F2....,5
User1_F1,User1_F2,......................Item3_F1,Item3_F2....,1
```

// `User1_F1` (shows the feature of `user1`) & `Item3_F1` (shows the feature of `item3`) and so on...

testing data will be:
`User1_F1`,`User1_F2`,......................`Item6_F1`,`Item6_F2`....,?
Please correct me if i am wrong....
Here,as we can see class `label1` comes only one time but `class5` comes two times, how to remove this imbalanced dataset problem?
And also tell me how to handle imbalanced data or any tool that can do pre-processing before applying recommendation on this data?

Comment: what do you mean by imbalanced dataset in a recommender system?

Comment: As you know not every user gives rating to every item, so there is a situation when user had given some  ratings. To make prediction for a particular user if we want to use their given item rating as training set and unknown item set as test set..then definitely in the training set there may be a case that some class label (rating) comes few times or may be absent. in this situation how the system will train from the absent class label and thus only predict the ratings that comes with more instances in the training set.